# How do I associate changed lines with functions in a git repository of C code?

Tags: c++, c, regex, git, parsing

I'm attempting to construct a “heatmap” from a multi-year history stored in a git repository where the unit of granularity is individual functions. Functions should grow hotter as they change more times, more frequently, and with more non-blank lines changed.

As a start, I examined the output of

```
git log --patch -M --find-renames --find-copies-harder --function-context -- *.c
```

I looked at using [Language.C](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c) from Hackage, but it seems to want a complete translation unit—expanded headers and all—rather being able to cope with a source fragment.

The `--function-context` option is new since version 1.7.8. The foundation of the implementation [in v1.7.9.4 is a regex](http://github.com/git/git/blob/a46034819ecce6872bff099f3d75589f4d38c00c/userdiff.c#L117):

```
PATTERNS("cpp",
         /* Jump targets or access declarations */
         "!^[ \t]*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*:.*$\n"
         /* C/++ functions/methods at top level */
         "^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*([ \t*]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*([ \t]*::[ \t]*[^[:space:]]+)?){1,}[ \t]*\\([^;]*)$\n"
         /* compound type at top level */
         "^((struct|class|enum)[^;]*)$",
         /* -- */
         "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
         "|[-+0-9.e]+[fFlL]?|0[xXbB]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[lL]?"
         "|[-+*/<>%&^|=!]=|--|\\+\\+|<<=?|>>=?|&&|\\|\\||::|->"),
```

This seems to recognize boundaries reasonably well but doesn’t always leave the function as the first line of the diff hunk, *e.g.*, with `#include` directives at the top or with a hunk that contains multiple function definitions. An option to tell diff to emit separate hunks for each function changed would be really useful.

This isn’t safety-critical, so I can tolerate some misses. Does that mean I likely have Zawinski’s [“two problems”](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)?

Comment: Very interesting question! Finally something other than "I'm new to git, how do I undo a commit?". Waiting for the heavy artillery to march in (i.e. VonC) :)

Comment: Would you please confirm the source language is C or C++?

Comment: @gbulmer The source language is C. `git diff` uses the same pattern internally to recognize function definitions in C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this suggestion is a bit tangential, but it may help in order to clarify and rank requirements. This would work for C or C++ ...

Instead of trying to find text blocks which are functions and comparing them, use the compiler to make binary blocks. Specifically, for every C/C++ source file in a change set, compile it to an object. Then use the object code as a basis for comparisons.

This might not be feasible for you, but IIRC there is an option on gcc to compile so that each function is compiled to an 'independent chunk' within the generated object code file. The linker can pull each 'chunk' into a program. (It is getting pretty late here, so I will look this up in the morning, if you are interested in the idea. )

So, assuming we can do this, you'll have lots of functions defined by chunks of binary code, so a simple 'heat' comparison is 'how much longer or shorter is the code between versions for any function?'

I am also thinking it might be practical to use objdump to reconstitute the assembler for the functions. I might use some regular expressions at this stage to trim off the register names, so that changes to register allocation don't cause too many false positive (changes).

I might even try to sort the assembler instructions in the function bodies, and diff them to get a pattern of "removed" vs "added" between two function implementations. This would give a measure of change which is pretty much independent of layout, and even somewhat independent of the order of some of the source.

So it might be interesting to see if two alternative implementations of the same function (i.e. from different a change set) are the same instructions :-)

This approach should also work for C++ because all names have been appropriately mangled, which should guarantee the same functions are being compared.

So, the regular expressions might be kept very simple :-)

Assuming all of this is straightforward, what might this approach fail to give you?

Side Note: This basic strategy could work for any language which targets machine code, as well as VM instruction sets like the Java VM Bytecode, .NET CLR code, etc too.

Comment: This would be thrown off by inlining and optimizer settings

Comment: That's an interesting approach. This particular repo depends on a library in another repo, so I'd have to walk back through both histories at different rates to try to keep the client repo compilable (*i.e.*, appropriate declarations and headers available).

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I was assuming compilation options would be the same, and that should be straightforward to arrange. I am assuming the compiler is not too chaotic (in the fractal sense). By sorting the opcodes within a function, and deleting register names the differences in the actual code would indicate how much "effective" change has happened. This isn't perfect, but IMHO is an interesting alternative to a textual comparison. For the same compiler options, functions which have actually not changed at the generated code level, but have had textual changes, might also be an interesting analysis.

Comment: @Greg Bacon - I did realise it is quite a lot of 'house keeping'. But it seems like an approach which is worth considering because it can strip away 'surface' changes. The compiler has a much simpler view of what is happening, and its ability take a 'whole function' view can be better than a persons in some cases. I'd actually advocate both a textual and a generated-code comparison if you really wanted to discover some interesting insights.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth considering building a simple parser, using one of the common tools, rather than just using regular expressions. Clearly it is better to choose something you are familiar with, or which your organisation already uses.

For this problem, a parser doesn't actually need to validate the code (I assume it is valid when it is checked in), and it doesn't need to understand the code, so it might be quite dumb.

It might throw away comments (retaining new lines), ignore the contents of text strings, and treat program text in a very simple way. It mainly needs to keep track of balanced '{' '}', balanced '(' ')' and all the other valid program text is just individual tokens which can be passed 'straight through'.

It's output might be a separate file/function to make tracking easier.

If the language is C or C++, and the developers are reasonably disciplined, they might never use 'non-syntactic macros'. If that is the case, then the files don't need to be preprocessed.

Then a parser is mostly just looking for a the function name (an identifier) at file scope followed by ( parameter-list )  { ... code ... }

I'd SWAG it would be a few days work using yacc & lex / flex & bison, and it might be so simple that their is no need for the parser generator.

If the code is Java, then ANTLR is a possible, and I think there was a simple Java parser example.

If Haskell is your focus, their may be student projects published which have made a reasonable stab at a parser.

Comment: That sounds similar to the approach I've been sketching. I want to know the range of lines in the diff hunk that belong to a given function definition. Matching the outermost curly braces is fiddly because of extra unbalanced braces due to lines being added or removed.

Comment: @Greg Bacon - ah! I think I understood! I am thinking of another approach, but I need something to eat. I may propose a `third way"?